# How to design Nginx location for microservice?

Tags: nginx, microservices

We have 10 Microservices-based applications. Each of them has about 15 services. So, we have 150 different service URLs for our product.

My question: How to design the Nginx location?

1) One location per application

2) One location per URL

3) Other way

I thinks there are something to trade off.

a. config complexity

b. conflict location issue

c. affection when micro-service refactor

d. nginx.conf size

Could someone give me some guidance or the best practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to give you an example of one of my own configuration. I cannot say this is the best way to do it, but I did refer/read a lot of blogs before making this up.

```
worker_processes 1;

events { worker_connections 10000; }

http {

  sendfile on;

  gzip              on;
  gzip_http_version 1.0;
  gzip_proxied      any;
  gzip_min_length   999;
  gzip_disable      "MSIE [1-6]\.";
  gzip_types        text/plain text/xml text/css
                    text/comma-separated-values
                    text/javascript
                    application/x-javascript;

  # List of application servers
  upstream company_api_servers {

  server company.xxxx.xxxx:port_number;

  }
  upstream community_api_servers {

  server community.xxxx.xxxx:port_number;

  }
  upstream devices_api_servers {

  server devices.xxxx.xxxx:port_number;

  }


    # Configuration for the server
    server {

    # Running port
    listen 80;

    # Proxying the Companies API
    location /companies {

    proxy_pass         http://company_api_servers;
    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;

    }
    # Proxying the Communities API
    location /communities {

    proxy_pass         http://community_api_servers;
    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;

    }
    # Proxying the Devices API
    location /devices {

    proxy_pass         http://devices_api_servers;
    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Great help~So, your design is option 1 style. And it seems that these 3 locations are totally isolated and will never exchange some service in future refactor. So, it's stable and reasonable.

Comment: Yup. This works perfectly for the applications we have. Also like I said, **this is just a sample**, you can build on it, as per your specific needs.

Comment: Finally, our PO decide to use one location per URL option. The reason is that our service is designed to be platform level, not just a application. So, other application will use our service URL. So, the URL itself needs well design and could not be affected by Nginx location limit.

However, I'm not sure if other platform level service also need this kinds of design. Anyway, thanks for your recommendation.